# passing a pandas dataframe to javascript as tabulated array

Tags: javascript, php, python, pandas, bokeh

This may be a very simple problem, but I am totaly new to javascript and cannot figure it out.

I am working on to create a bokeh plot which updates ColumnDataSource on click.
Inside the javascript callback I am using ajax call and then php to take an updated pandasdf from server and most part is working well and fine so far.

Try passing an pandas dataframe as json, I keep failing.
I have tried several answers posted here, but all of them pass array as string somehow.

Here is simplified reproduction of problem.

submit.html
submits form and then take an array from response.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<html>
   <body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
    var data1 = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data1 = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data1);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php",
      data: data1,
      success: function(data) {
        console.table(data)
        $(".the-return").html(
        "return: " + data["index"]
        );

        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["index"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>


    <form action="return.php" class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <input type="text" name="st_numbers" value="" placeholder="write something" />
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"  />
    </form>

    <div class="the-return">
      [HTML is replaced when successful.]
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

response.php

```
<?php
\\ a call to server-side python code to calculate and print( df.reset_index().to_dict('list'))
\\ $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
\\ exec($python." server_side_calc.py ".$query, $return)

\\ what it is doing is essentially the same as;
echo json_encode(["{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'p': [10, 20, 30, 50], 'init': [0.5178, 0.11115, 0.1903, 0.026], '24': [0.385, 0.028, 0.104, -0.0052]}"]);
?>
```

These programs reads pandas dataframe as string `"{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'p': [10, 20, 30, 50], 'init': [0.5178, 0.11115, 0.1903, 0.026], '24': [0.385, 0.028, 0.104, -0.0052]}"`
I have no idea where the outermost blakets [] went and why it cannot be recognized as an array.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you for your help.

Yui